# Problems with lookahead in RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I still have problems with regex lookahead. In this example here I'm not sure if I misunderstand the intention of lookahead or of I just use the wrong syntax.

## Initial situation

The input lines can look like this, where `one` and `two` should be the result.

1. `[[one][two]]`
2. `[[one]]`

The `][` in the middle is optional.

My initial regex pattern only fits two the first example.

```
^\[\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]\]$
```

Resulting in

[image]

## First modification

I extend my pattern because of the optional `][` with a "non capturing group".

```
^\[\[(.*)(?:\]\[)?(.*)\]\]$
```

Resulting in

[image]

## Second modification with lookahead

Now IMHO the lookahead comes into account. Am I right? The first group should "catch" (extract the string) only until `][` appears. The `][` is like a stop sign.

Now I'm digging in the fog with things like that not working:

```
^\[\[((?!\]\[).*)(\]\[)?(.*)\]\]$
```

Comment: Can the input(s) in each line contain `[` and/or `]` themselves? If there's no funny business like that then you don't need lookahead – you can just specify `[^\[\]]` instead of `.` within each capturing group: `^\[\[([^\[\]]*)(?:\]\[)?([^\[\]]*)\]\]$`

Comment: I believe if you make modifier in your first group lazy (for first modification) regex will work for you even without lookaheads. `^\[\[(.*?)(?:\]\[)?(.*)\]\]$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^\[\[([^][]*)(?:]\[([^][]*))?]]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HxVQVC/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\[\[` - a `[[` string
- `([^][]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `(?:]\[([^][]*))?` - an optional sequence of `][` + Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `]]` - a `]]` substring
- `$` - end of string.

If you can have any chars between `[[` and `][`, and then between `][` and last `]]`, you can use

```
^\[\[((?:(?!]\[).)*)(?:]\[(.*))?]]$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HxVQVC/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\[\[` - a `[[` string
- `((?:(?!]\[).)*)` - Group 1: any char other than line break chars, zero or more but as many as possible occurrences, that does not start the `][` char sequence
- `(?:]\[(.*))?` - an optional sequence of `][`, then Group 2 capturing any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `]]` - a `]]` string
- `$`  - end of string.

Comment: The second fits the best to my needs. But I have to carefully read the explanation step by step and very concentrated on regex101 to understand what is going on here. :D

Comment: @buhtz There is only one more thing: if there can be only one `][`, the second version will work. If your strings can have multiple `][`s, then 1) if Group 1 should stop at the first `][`, replace `((?:(?!]\[).)*)` with `((?:(?!]\[).)*?)` (make it lazy), or 2) if Group 1 must grab all up to the last `][`, use the second regex as it is now.